# Laravel Passport create fresh API token for Guzzle HTTP Client

Tags: ajax, laravel, axios, guzzle, laravel-passport

Apparently, am able to consume my own API via Javascript using VueJs' Axios and jQuery's Ajax but the same has failed to work with Guzzle HTTP client.

How can I use the **[CreateFreshApiToken](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript) middleware** with Guzzle.

**Axios - Ok**

```
axios.get('api/user').then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response.data);
});
```

**Ajax - OK**

```
window.$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'api/user',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        console.error(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

**Guzzle - Failed**

```
try {
    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'http://localhost/passport-test/public/api/',
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
        ],
    ]);

    $api_response = $client->request('GET', 'user', ['debug' => true]);

    $user = json_decode($api_response->getBody(), true);

    return response()->json($user);
} catch (ConnectException $ex) {
    return response()->json(['code' => $ex->getCode(), 'message' => $ex->getMessage()]);
} catch (ClientException $ex) {
    return json_decode($ex->getResponse()->getBody(), true);
} catch (ServerException $ex) {
    return response()->json(['code' => $ex->getCode(), 'message' => $ex->getMessage()]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `createFreshApiTokens` attaches a cookie for authorization, but when you are using guzzle you are not making a request from the client side ( browser ) so the cookie is not attached to the request!

Comment: Yah. But I was trying to figure out how to achieve the same using guzzle.

For now I have to consume my own API like any other third party app.

Comment: you need to put the token in the header. 'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' + $token.

Comment: or send the token in a cookie [laravel_token]. but why do you want to use a cookie in this this situation?

Comment: The web application is in a separate from the application source code.

"api.example.com" is the api and "example.com" is the web app

Comment: and you want your api to use cookies for auth?